# How can I change the decal on my vehicles?

Tags: planetside-2

I've seen vehicles with decals saying PlanetSide Beta and others. How do I put one of these decals on my vehicle? And how do I get some more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To apply them, open the pause menu, go to the vehicle tab, select the vehicle you want to customize, and choose a loadout:
[image]

Then pick "Apperance":
[image]

Then go to the decal tab, pick the decal you want, return to the game, and spawn a vehicle with that loadout.
[image]
To get more decals, click "Get More".

That will take to you to this screen where you can filter to decals and unlock ones that you want for Station Cash:
[image]

Alternatively, you can buy them buy just going to the store tab and picking "Vehicle Gear":
[image]

Comment: Nice visual aids.
It's really too bad that the decals are so tiny on most vehicles...